# Deep linking and FBSessionDelegate in Facebook iOS SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, deep-linking

I've read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app/ and I am confused on how I am supposed to handle deep linking in 3.0. Say the user clicks an appRequest for my app and FB opens my app with a special URL. I have my Appdelegate's openURL method do:

```
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
```

The tutorial says:

```
If your app requires an authorized user, handle the processing of the target URL in the
SDK callbacks implemented after a successful login, the fbDidLogin method.
```

However, the fbDidLogin delegate method is no longer called because in 3.0 we switch to using FBSession.activeSession instead of using a facebook.m object. In fact, none of the FBSessionDelegate methods will ever be called because the facebook object's state is never changed. So where should I process the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You would likely handle this in the handler you've set up when opening a session.

Say for example that you opened the session using something like:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
```

You could put put the deep linking handling code in the method set to handle session changes that you can define, ex:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // Handle deep link      
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
            self.user = nil;
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            self.user = nil;
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

To see a working sample for deep link handling, see https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe/